# in view of the fact that

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to talk about my algorithm and why I have used the data of the next stop but one (after next). So can I use **In view of  the fact that** in this form?

> **In view of  the fact that** many stops are located close to each other, the data of the after next stop was taken into consideration to determine which next stop was served by the bus.

Comment: In principle your cited usage is valid, but I'm sure 9 out of 10 native speakers would use a simpler form, such as ***as, since*** or ***because***. Why make life difficult for both yourself and your audience? Particularly since "viewing the fact" and "taking into consideration" are effectively the same process here.

Answer (score 1):

**in view of the fact that** is a fairly common, though a little bit formal, way to say **in light of the fact that** which basically means **because** or **as a result of**. Take a look at this example sentence:

> **In view of the fact that** the defendant was extremely drunk at the time the murder took place, this might be taken as further evidence that in fact he did not commit the crime he stands accused of because the level of physical incapacitation caused by the alcohol intoxication had made him virtually unable to do that.

Substituting **in view of the fact that** for **because** doesn't change the meaning of the sentence a bit. Thus, the two usages are completely equivalent from a semantic perspective.

So, in answer to your question, yes, you can use this expression in your sentence. It sounds totally natural to say something like that in formal writing.

And when writing, try to italicize special vocabulary terms. Otherwise, it might be a little bit hard to read for people who are not familiar well enough with the subject you're discussing.

PS: Though the part that comes directly before the comma is very clear, overall the sentence is poorly written. It's quite difficult to make proper sense of what you're trying to say there.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like your algorithm is trying to determine the pathways between stops and there is ambiguity if you only had a **one-stop look-ahead**.  By using the **stop-after-next-stop** the ambiguity can be resolved. It is a **look-back** algorithm.

**In view of the fact** is perfectly fine to describe the concern that the stops are close to each other, though it is wordy, **since** or **because** might be a more concise alternative since they also imply *factual* information:

> **Since** many stops are located close to each other...
>   **Because** many stops are located close to each other...

the rest of the sentence:

> ...the data of the after next stop was taken into consideration to determine which next stop was served by the bus.

sounds clumsy. In all, three stops are considered by the algorithm: ***A***) **the current stop**; ***B***) **the next stop**; ***C***) the **stop-after-the-next-stop**.  According to your description, from (***A***) by only looking at the **next stop**(***B***) it is not possible to determine the stop(***C***), however, looking at the **stop-after-next-stop**(***C***), it is possible to determine the stop *in-between*(***B***)

> (***A***) -> (***B***)is one-to-many
>   (***B***) -> (***C***) is many-to-many
>   however, (***C***) -> (***B***) -> (***A***) is unique

[NB: it would be interesting to see this graph]

You could reformulate your sentence to say:

> ...the **stop-after-next-stop** was used to determine which stops the bus used.

The word **data** is not necessary since it seems only the pathway is of concern and not any other measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it is look-back algorithm and  if I know Stop A and Stop C, then I can determine which stop B is.